# Getting user data from Active Directory with Windows Authentication .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on project where I need to access an Active Directory and get user data from there, like a phone book. With the Windows Authentication [WA] set at the creation of the project, It somehow automatically gets my account that is currently logged in to the computer in the following format:

[DOMAIN][username]

I don't know whether it's already communicating with the AD or just the current Windows login. My goal is to be able to log into the AD from both an internal and an external connection, and get data based on the roles the AD gives.

The default program gets the information like this with Razor:

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

So I'm able to extract the username like this:

```
AppUser temp = new AppUser
        {
            Username = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name                          
        };
```

But this is obviously not enough to get by, and this won't authenticate me to the AD. The credentials are the same on the computer and on the AD, so in theory it should be possible.

My goal is to authenticate with the Windows Authentication the internal site without the need to log in again, but when accessing from an external site it still requires the credentials. This  is an extension of a currently active project, so most of the backend is written, so it would be great if this was possible by using the current interfaces with new services underneath.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you look at using [Novell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Novell.Directory.Ldap/) library?